# Ensure static variable is initialized before inject provider

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

We have an Angular6 application which use a globalcontextServiceFactory to initialize application before renderer views.

This works with a subscription to get configuration to back-end endpoint and after launch forkJoin to get environment application datas.

Issue comes from a provider which use static variable to save/store configuration retrieved from subscription. 
Considering hierarchical dependency injectors, this providers used provideIn: 'root' injector.

```js
app.module.ts


export function contextServiceFactory(contextService: ContextService): Function {return () => contextService.init();}


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [...,
    {provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: contextServiceFactory, deps: [ContextService], multi: true}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```js
context.service.ts

@Injectable()
export class ContextService{
  constructor(...){}

init() {
       this.configSubscription = this.getConfig().subscribe((config: Config) => {
      ConfigService.config = config;
        this.globalSubscription = forkJoin(
        this.getDatas1(),
        this.getDatas2(),
        this.getDatas3()
      ).subscribe((response: Object) => {
        this.setDatas1(response[0]),
        this.setDatas2(response[1]),
        this.setDatas3(response[2])
        this.contextInitialized.next(true);
        this.inj.get(Router).initialNavigation(); // <-- Init router when all responses are retrieved
      });
    });
```

```js
config.service.ts

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigService {
  private static _configuration: Config;

  public static get config(): Config {
    return ConfigService._configuration;
  }

  public static set config(config: Config) {
    ConfigService._configuration = config;
  }
}
```

```js
test.service.ts

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {

  foo: boolean;

  constructor(private contextService: ContextService) { // ContextService is called here because used inside TestService - not describe here

// THIS WORK
// We have to wait context is initalized before set 'foo'
/*    this.contextService.contextInitialized.subscribe((isInit: boolean) => {
      if (isInit) {
        this.foo = ConfigService.config.bar;
      }
    });*/

// THIS NOT WORK
    this.foo = ConfigService.config.bar;
  }
}
```

We have this error from console because TestService is call after ContextService but before static variable is initalized by init()

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined
    at new TestService (test.service.ts)
    at TestService_Factory (test.service.ts)

Question : is it possible to wait application is fully loaded before use static value store in other service ?

Thks

Comment: *global static variables* === **bad**

Comment: Thks but what kind of solutions you advocate ? Knowing that my ConfigService  provide to my components certains key/appId of config, you suggest to keep config not static, construct an object in each component, import in all constructor and add to test unit only for some key/appId of configuration which are not treatment after/before consuming...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of is going async using rx:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigService {
  private static _configuration = new ReplaySubject<Config>(1);

  public static config$ = this._configuration.asObservable();

  public static setConfig(config: Config) {
    this._configuration.next(config);
  }
}
```

But you need to go async all the way (which is not a bad thing in my opinion):

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {

  foo$: Observable<boolean> = ConfigService.config$.pipe(map(config => config.foo));

  // you don't even need the contextService anymore :), config is pushed when it's available
  constructor(private contextService: ContextService) {

  }

  async getFooValue(): Promise<boolean> {
    const firstFooValue = await this.foo$.pipe(first()).toPromise();
    // this will get the first available value or wait for it (wrapped in a promise)
    return firstFooValue;
  }
}
```

Now, responding to your question... Yes, it's possible to block the application until something is loaded but that's not the greatest user experience and you still need to use promises/observables to "block" it.

Your `contextservice.init` needs to be async (return a promise or an observable) in order for angular to know when it's done.

This could be a fix:

```
async init() {
    const config = await this.getConfig().toPromise();
    ConfigService.config = config;
    const response = await forkJoin(
        this.getDatas1(),
        this.getDatas2(),
        this.getDatas3()
    ).toPromise();
    this.setDatas1(response[0]);
    this.setDatas2(response[1]);
    this.setDatas3(response[2]);
    this.contextInitialized.next(true);
    this.inj.get(Router).initialNavigation(); // <-- Init router when all responses are retrieved
}
```

Comment: I upvoted because you fixed the problem, but technically there is no need now to use `APP_INITIALIZER` at all. Since reading config is now async it no longer needs to prevent the app from loading. You can just move the code from `init()` to `ConfigService`. All consumers now have to wait for it to emit now. So why stop the app from loading?

Comment: @Andrei Tãtar thanks a lot for your comment. With the help of your answer i have simplify my init() method with this and it works like a charm : typescript `async init() {

    ConfigService.config = await this.getconfig().toPromise();
    await forkJoin(
        this.getDatas1(),
...
    ).subscribe((ret: Object) => {
     this.setDatas1(response[0]);
...
    this.contextInitialized.next(true);
    this.inj.get(Router).initialNavigation();
    });

  }` Not need to update my ConfigService with ReplaySubject